# why room Database data loading is very long and slow

Tags: android, database, caching

I use the room database for cache some data in my app.but when I run the app in the emulator or my real phone, it usually takes 5 seconds to load data from the database and show ... this is very long time ... even my data is few
Can anyone help me to resolve this?
thank you

ordeeDao.java:

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_orders")
        List<Orders> getOrders();
```

and my CacheDatabase class :

```
 @Database(entities = {Orders.class}, version = 1,exportSchema = false)
       public abstract class CacheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

            private static CacheDatabase INSTANCE;

            public abstract OrdersDao ordersDao();

            public static CacheDatabase getInMemoryDatabase(Context context) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE =
                            Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), CacheDatabase.class, "CacheDb.sql")
                                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                                    .build();
                }
                return INSTANCE;
            }

            public static void destroyInstance() {
                INSTANCE = null;
            }
        DataBase.java:
          public JSONArray getOrders(){
                try {
                    return new JSONArray(new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(db.ordersDao().getOrders()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
             private void SetOrdersDB() {
                JSONArray ordersArray=db.getOrders();
                List<MainPojo.Order> ordersList=new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0;i<ordersArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject object;
                    MainPojo.Order order=new MainPojo.Order();
                    try {
                        object=ordersArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        order.setId(object.getInt("id"));
                        order.setTicket_id(object.getString("ticket_id"));
                        order.setService(object.getString("service"));
                        order.setStatus(object.getString("status"));
                        order.setType(object.getString("type"));
                        order.setFromCurrency(object.getString("from_currency"));
                        order.setFromAmount(object.getString("from_amount"));
                        order.setToCurrency(object.getString("to_currency"));
                        order.setToAmount(object.getString("to_amount"));
                        order.setPayableAmount(object.getString("payable_amount"));
                        order.setFee(object.getString("fee"));
                        order.setDiscount(object.getString("discount"));
                        order.setPaymentMethod(object.getString("payment_method"));
                        order.setPaymentGateway(object.getString("payment_gateway"));
                        order.setPaymentRef(object.getString("payment_ref"));
                        order.setPayedAt(object.getString("payed_at"));
                        order.setExpiresAt(object.getString("expires_at"));
                        order.setHandledAt(object.getString("handled_at"));
                        order.setCreatedAt(object.getString("created_at"));
                        order.setUpdatedAt(object.getString("updated_at"));
                        order.setIcon(object.getString("icon"));
                        order.setAmount(object.getString("amount"));
                        ordersList.add(order);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
                ordersFragment=new OrdersFragment(ordersList,this);
            }
```

Comment: How can we help if you don`t help us? Please show us the code and generate logs if possible.

Comment: it depends on your  programming skills how you write the code.

Comment: show your code .

Comment: post your code compatriot!

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Code added to my question

Comment: @ManoharReddy Code added to my question

Comment: @mohammadRezaAbiri tnx for editing